# Semaphores and shared memory

Tags: c, multiprocessing, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a question regarding multiprocess  programming in C, I have several reader processes that will be reading from a file into a shared buffer and several writer processes reading from the buffer and into another file, what type of semaphores will we need to use for this. and how can we use shared memory with the semaphores.

Comment: What operating system? Are you using any multiprocessing specific libraries?

Comment: linux here are all the headers I included in the file,
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <time.h>

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you're on linux, one easy option is to use [pshared mutexes](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared) and condition variables. A recet version of glibc will be necessary. Essentially inside your shared memory segment you will have something like:

```
struct shmem_head {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
};
```

To initialize:

```
void init_shmem_head(struct shmem_head *head)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED );

    pthread_mutex_init(&head->mutex, &attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&head->mutex);
}
```

You now have a mutex, shared by all processes with the shared memory segment open. You can simply use `pthread_mutex_lock` to lock and `pthread_mutex_unlock` to unlock as normal. There's also a similar [`pthread_condattr_setpshared`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_condattr_setpshared) if you want condition variables as well.